# change scale of animating sprite in cocos 2d x

Tags: animation, cocos2d-x, ccsprite, cocos2d-x-3.0

How can I make the animating sprite smaller as my images are very larger. I tried `bird->setScale(0.5f);` but I it didn't decrease the scale.
following is my code to animate the sprite.

```
int numframe = 3;
CCArray* frames = CCArray::createWithCapacity(numframe);

CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("bird-anim.plist");
CCSpriteFrameCache* frameCache = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();


char file[100] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < numframe; i++)
{
    sprintf(file, "bird-anim%d.png", i+1);
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = frameCache->spriteFrameByName(file);
    frames->addObject(frame);
}

CCAnimation* animation = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(frames, 0.1);
CCAnimate* animate = CCAnimate::create(animation);
CCRepeatForever* repeat = CCRepeatForever::create(animate);

bird->runAction(repeat);
bird->setScale(0.7);
```

Comment: I don't see, in the code above where you  have a `bird` object...

Comment: @GameDeveloper   bird is here :)      in my header file   game.h CCSprite * bird.    Now have you seen the bird ? Now please provide me proper guidance that how I can resize or setScale for an animating sprite

Comment: I did in your other question about this.

Comment: I found nothing wrong in the code... Ideally it should work fine.. Just try to scale the bird before applying animation.. Its just a try... :)